# 'exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()' error in android 7 and above

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, fileopener2

when I m going to open pdf file in android 7 and above i m getting above error.i am using the Cordova-file-opener2 plugin.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was facing the same issue.use this plugin

```
<plugin spec="https://github.com/tectronik/cordova-plugin-file-opener2-tectronik.git"/>
```

Comment: Works for me.Thanks!!

Comment: the plugin doesn't work as well, the installation fails